# Ruby + WebDriver > Selecting from dropdown in Angular 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby, selenium, capybara

I have the following HTML:

```html
<div class="modal-content" uib-modal-transclude="">
   <form class="ng-pristine ng-scope ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-maxlength ng-valid-leftover-text" pb-submit="form.$valid && ctrl.submit()" name="form" novalidate="">
     <div class="modal-header">
       <div class="modal-body">
         <!-- ngIf: authentication.user.isCustomer -->
           <div class="form-group ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-maxlength" ng-form="">
              <div class="form-group ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" ng-form="">
                <label class="control-label" for="pill">Pill</label>
                  <select id="pill" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" required="" ng-disabled="ctrl.readOnly" ng-options="i.name as i.name for i in ctrl.pills" ng-model="ctrl.group.pill">
                   <option value="?" selected="selected"/>
                   <option label="Red Pill" value="Red Pill">Red Pill</option>
                   <option label="Blue Pill" value="string:Blue Pill">Blue Pill</option>
```

I am using Selenium WebDriver with Ruby and several gems, including Capybara. I am trying to choose the Red Pill (obviously) via the dropdown selector. So far, I have tried the following:

```js
find('#pill').find(:xpath, "//*[@id='pill']/option[2]").select_option

find(:xpath, "//*[@id='pill']/option[2]").select_option

select_by(:value, 'string:Red Pill')

select('Red Pill', from: 'pill')

find('option', :text => 'Red Pill').click

find(:xpath, "//div[contains(text(), 'Red Pill')]/..").click
```

Ruby accepts the above commands (i.e. the syntax is OK), and even engages the dropdown (when I click on it, all the options are displayed), but it doesn't seem to know what to do and simply moves on to the next step without making any selection or otherwise failing.

My suspicion is that this is all because of Angular 1, such that this is not technically a dropdown but something else. Any thoughts?

Comment: have you tried the standard select syntax: `page.select('foo', from: 'bar')`? http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Actions#select-instance_method

Comment: Yes. Returns the following error: Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find option "Red Pill" with id pill.

Comment: If the HTML posted is actually the html on the page during the test run, and `select('Red Pill', from: 'pill')` is returning ElementNotFound, then it means the select isn't actually visible on the page, have you performed whatever action is necessary to make the modal visible?  (Note: Your claimed error message  of' Unable to find option "Red Pill" with id pill.' doesn't make any sense though since Capybara shouldn't produce that error message for that call, unless you also passed an `:id` option which would be wrong usage)

Answer (score 0):

first(:option, "Red Pill").select_option